# How to make a line break in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var options = { title: 'Dates:  \n' + start_date + ' \n ' + end_date };
```

This is not working. How can I have an output like this?

Dates: 
Date1
Date2

Comment: You writing to html? How about `<br/>`?

Comment: You should use `<br />` instead of `\n` if you are outputting html

Comment: `<br />` is printing it on screen and not making a line break

Comment: What about telling us where you want to output that?

Comment: where are you adding the data?

Comment: I am pretty sure i read it. Display it where? In a html element? In a console.log? Draw it on a canvas? If that sounded harsh, please forgive me. It was not my intention to offend you.

Comment: @skdnewbie - gameower is trying to help you, the problem is we need more info in order to help you, instead of editing the inner html of the element you are updating the inner text

Comment: Please add a code snippet where the output happens. This question is far too vague without that information.

Comment: Ok, Im using google visualization API..I want to display it near a chart.

Comment: What is the output if you go with \n ? Does it display "Dates:  \n date 1 ..."

Comment: No, it display Dates: date1 ... but dont make the break

Comment: Please update your question with your output code! I don't think we can help you without that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ive found another solution to this problem. Thanks to all ;)

Ive created a div to write what I want there.

Answer (score 1):

1. javascript doesn't have a line break.
2. So as for HTML.
3. HTML has styling elements and CSS which can cause a line break, like `<br>`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends where you want to output your text.

If the output in html, the line break will not be visible on rendering.

If the output is an alert box, then the line break is \n indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = { title: "Dates:  <br/>" + start_date + " <br/> " + end_date };
```

Comment: Dont work, ive tried it before. If I do that, output: Dates: <br> Date1...

Comment: @skdnewbie Show your full source.